# C# Subscribing to Events Using Interfaces

Tags: c#, events, interface, event-handling

I have recently started working with C# events and I am really liking the ease of use they offer (I come from a java background where we have to do all this event stuff manually).

However, there is one thing from my java background that I am missing: the inheritance side.

In java, if you want to subscribe to an event, you would inherit an interface such as IKeyListener. The interface would contain all of the method event signatures which you would then implement in the subscribing class. Whenever a key would be pressed, these implemented methods would be fired. Much the same as C#. However, unlike in java, I am unable to identify which classes subscribe to certain events because they don't actually inherit anything.

So if I wanted a list of objects which have key press event support I could do

```
List<IKeyListener> keyListeners = new ArrayList<IKeyListener>();
```

However, I don't see any good way to do this in C#. How would I be able to create list similar to the one above? Preferably without much "hackiness".

Thank you.

Comment: While you mention Java in your question, the question itself is not about creating a Java program, and so the [tag:java] question tag is not appropriate. I've deleted it for you.

Answer (score 3):

In C# you can define the event in an interface like this:

```
public interface IDrawingObject  
{  
    event EventHandler ShapeChanged;  
}
```

Then you can do what you want and store them like this:

```
var shapes = new List<IDrawingObject>();
```

A class can then implement the interface like this:

```
public class Shape : IDrawingObject  
{  
    public event EventHandler ShapeChanged;  
    void ChangeShape()  
    {  
        // Do something here before the event…  

        OnShapeChanged(new MyEventArgs(/*arguments*/));  

        // or do something here after the event.   
    }  
    protected virtual void OnShapeChanged(MyEventArgs e)  
    {  
        if(ShapeChanged != null)  
        {  
           ShapeChanged(this, e);  
        }  
    }  
}
```

So in other words the event becomes part of the interface and if a class implements that interface, the class must provide an implementation for the event as well. That way you are safe to assume the implementing class has the event.

Finally every event will need to share some info about the event. That class can inherit the `EventArgs` class like below:

```
public class MyEventArgs : EventArgs   
{  
    // class members  
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I am looking for. But what if I don't want the Shape class to be the class that "fires" the event? I am wanting to have one class call the event and then have another class subscribe to the event being called. So lets say I have a Blueprint class which needs to know when a certain shape changes (and the shape is not a member of blueprint). How could I do this without having to also be the class which calls the event? It is also possible that I am totally missing something. If so please let me know, thank you :)

Comment: But why would you do that? The whole idea is for the class to have this knowledge and no one else. If I have a button with a click event, I want only the button to say it was clicked. I do not want other classes to say it was clicked because what if it wasn't.

Comment: @exonto If you want the `blueprint` class to know when the `shape` changes, then `blueprint` can subscribe to the `change` event of the `shape` class. But only `shape` should fire the event. All the code for when this event should be fired should be inside the `shape` class.

Comment: Now that I really think about it, what this really boils down to is this. I want to have some way to require a class to subscribe to an event. My thought being that interfaces require their methods to be implemented, which could then _somehow_ be used to require it to subscribe. I guess I just used the List example because it was something I had done before. But I see what you are saying in that I would be defeating the purpose. So with that said, allow me to rephrase my question. How can I ensure that a class is subscribed to an event?

Comment: The shape class in my example has this code `if(ShapeChanged != null)` which basically means if anyone has subscribed then notify them. Is that what you are asking now?